# Map sibling thead & tbody elements in React

Tags: reactjs

I ran into a situation where I need to spit out sibling `<thead>` `<tbody>` pairs in a loop, however adding a wrapping component throws an improper dom warning.

```
stuff.map(x =>
  <span>
    <thead>
      ...
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      ...
    </tbody>
  </span>
)
```

Desired:

```
<table>
  <thead>top level columns</thead>
  <thead>...</thead>
  <tbody>...</thead>
  <thead>...</thead>
  <tbody>...</tbody>
</table>
```

The wrapping span throws the "span cannot be child of table" warning. Is there a way of doing this without having multiple tables?

Answer (score 1):

*EDIT:* I didn't read the warning you got first - but still - the use of multiple thead elements within one table is not allowed per specification.

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/table.html#table

> **Permitted contents**
>
> An optional caption element, followed by zero or
>   more colgroup elements, followed by an optional thead element followed by
>
> **either**
>
> one tfoot element, followed by zero or more tbody
>   elements
>
> **or**
>
> one or more tr elements or zero or more tbody elements,
>   or one or more tr elements followed by an optional tfoot element

You might want to find a different way to get your desired styling, such as using classes on your rows instead.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can return arrays of elements!

```
stuff.map(x =>
  [
    <thead>
      ...
    </thead>,

    <tbody>
      ...
    </tbody>
  </span>
])
```